# Whole new project inside a jekyll project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jekyll

I have some website projects that I want to show case that have their own index.html files.

I want to make a route in my Jekyll website so that if I go `asdf.com/project1/` I would see simply my project1.

Is this possible to do?

My project is deployed on amazon AWS S3 buckets, hosted on Cloudfront. Should I upload to the bucket and set up some kind of routing?

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options, put those pages inside Jekyll as "projectname/index.html" or an html file without extension.

If you don't want Jekyll to process them and just use the html do not add front matter to it and jekyll will just copy them to the output folder.

Then you may need to set the right content type when uploading the website to the S3 bucket.

You may find helpful to put that into a script: https://simpleit.rocks/having-pretty-urls-in-a-jekyll-website-hosted-in-amazon-s3/

Answer (score 1):

If you want S3 to show a specific HTML page when navigating to `asdf.com/project1/` the easiest way to achieve this is by creating a file with corresponding key  `project1/index.html` in that bucket.

Source here (bottom of page): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html